# Are there programs for monitoring http requests sent from computer?

Tags: windows, networking

Are there programs for Windows that would enable me to listout all the http requests my computer sent to all web servers and monitor in real time?

Example, I visit website.com and that website would be listed in the listout?

Also, it would be great if this would be browser independent.

It would be cool if I could view responses too if that's not too much memory to hold.

Comment: I use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for this task. Saved my life several times.

Comment: Very nice... I'll check that one out. :)

Comment: Nice tool, indeed. Requires proxy configuration on the application side though.

Comment: On windows 7 and 8 this can be done using the performance monitoring too that is accessible by the task manager.

Answer (score 4):

A network analysis tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can be used for that. You can use it to monitor every network package that runs through your interface, you can define filters so that you only see HTTP packages.

[image: Wireshark displaying HTTP traffic]

Above you see a Screenshot of Wireshark recording HTTP GET requests originating from me browsing cnn.com from my web browser.

You can also filter both the requests and the responses.